# Is it possible to get SSH to forward empty arguments?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I'm trying to execute a remote script with SSH, and this script changes its behavior depending on whether or not a specific argument is empty. Here's a minimal example, where I created a simple `tmp.sh` file that echos the number of arguments and then what the arguments are. When I execute it locally, it works as expected, saying it got 3 arguments. But when I execute the script through SSH, it says it only got 2 arguments:

```
$ cat argtest.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo $#
echo $@
$ ./argtest.sh foo '' bar
3
foo bar
$ ssh user@localhost ./argtest.sh foo '' bar
2
foo bar
```

Is there a way to get SSH to forward the empty argument, so the script says it got 3 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  ssh user@localhost "./argtest.sh foo '' bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar with my remote Perl invocations that should work for your bash script as well - with some bash syntax changes, of course...

Use environment variables to "pass variables" (set or otherwise) to the remote process.  For instance,

```
$ ssh me@localhost 'VAR1="var1 text" /tmp/try.pl'
```

then, in your remote script, just check for variable existence, as in:

```
$ cat /tmp/try.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
if ($ENV{VAR1}) { print "$ENV{VAR1}\n"; }
if ($ENV{VAR2}) { print "$ENV{VAR2}\n"; }
```

so when the above is invoked

```
$ ssh me@localhost 'VAR1="var1 text" /tmp/try.pl'
var1 text
```

As you can see, I was able to check for the input variable existence on the remote call.

This should work for you.

Comment: Interesting. Neat idea.